# Pagination items move on hover and adding border

Tags: css

This menu items are moving when hover.How can I make the items static and not moving when hovering.
Same thing happens when putting a specific width and height.
Here's the NEW JSFiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/tagaawang/zTCCf/3/

/*CSS*/

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .div{margin:0 auto;position:relative;margin-top:40px;}
   .pagination{height: 42px;
        clear: right;
        top: -21px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;}
   .pagination ul{width: 100%;max-height: 42px;}
   .pagination li{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        list-style: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 23px;
        text-indent: 8px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #0083DE;
        height: 26px;
        font-size: 14px;display: inline-block;
        width: 26px;margin-left:10px;  }
    .pagination li.selected{background-color: white;
        border: 4px solid #F0F0F0;
        padding: 5px;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #0F7ABE;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
     .pagination li:hover{background-color: #0083DE;
        border: 4px solid #F0F0F0;
        padding: 5px;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}​
    </style>
```

**html**

```
<div class="div">
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li class="selected">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

​

Comment: I'm not seeing this in IE9, Firefox 16.0.1 or Chrome 22.0.1229.94. What browser?

Comment: You've missed off some lines of your CSS in your jsFiddle. The problem is you're adding a `border` on hover. `border` is not included in the width of an element unless you have set `{box-sizing: border-box}`.

Answer (score 4):

based on your code, the hover and/or selected state goes along with a border of 4px:

```
border: 4px solid #F0F0F0;
```

This causes a shift of 4 pixel offcourse, solution:

Add a border with same color as the background of your site as placeholder, then when hovering, change `border-color`.

```
.pagination li{
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}
.pagination li.selected, .pagination li:hover {
  border-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

Comment: There's also a `padding:5px` in the hover state adding to the movement.

Comment: Good suggestion.But the background has a texture.Ok I'll just try this anyway hope the QA don't mind the border.Thank you.

Comment: missed that one with the padding, this should be on the initial state of course.